# Using wild cards in windows with directories

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am running a Jenkins project which runs under Windows.  I have a dir to find a file (html file) from my directory.  This shows up

```
reports\All Smoke_2018-01-23T084148.270-0600\TestLog.html
```

I know the first directory will always be "reports" and the file name will be TestLog.html.  However, the middle directory (All Smoke_2018-01-23T084148.270-0600) will depend on the date and time.  So what I want to do is

```
 echo "some string" >> reports\*\TestLog.html
```

it will actually be more complicated than that.  But it does not appear to allow me to use an * as a directory name (as Unix would).

Is there another way to refer to the file?  I know find has /s which is how I find it and findstr also has a /b.  But how can I get the file name to echo to it?

Comment: If it's a Windows batch file, try something like `for /d %%I in (reports\*.*) do ...`

Comment: Does reports have other directories from previous dates? Do they all have TestLog.html in them?  Do you actually want to write to all of them?

Comment: The workspace is deleted after each build, so no.  Fresh workspace each time.  Only one log file.

Comment: Joe I will examine your suggestion.  Would %%I be the log file?

Comment: %%I would be the directory name.  Start by trying "... do echo %I", then adapt to your needs.

Comment: yes that worked.

Comment: for /d %%I in (reports\*.*) do (type reports\Claims.txt >> %%I\TestLog.html)